# Keeping a firefox tab on a remote server always on focus

Tags: firefox, webserver, whatsapp

I'm trying to keep WhatsApp Web always on focus in a Firefox tab on a remote server so that I always appear online.

So far I've tried connecting via sshx, starting a screen session and then opening Firefox with xpra so that I can connect/disconnect to the Firefox window. I've also installed Greasemonkey with the script from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/492335/how-can-i-make-a-tab-in-firefox-falsely-believe-that-it-still-has-the-focus) question to trick the tab into believing it is always on focus, but it is not working. Then, I've also tried the iMacros extension to simulate a click every 10 seconds but it's not working either.

I do not have root access so I cannot use a virtual machine, which is the only other way I can think of to make this work.

Comment: Remember that what you want still needs your phone to be online all the time as well. If you can manage that, I'd use something like https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsAPI instead of a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I managed to make it work with iMacros using a different recording mode.