# How to Disable Web Page Checks for Focus, or Spoof Focus on Firefox Browser Tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, focus, window-focus

**Problem**:
Some web sites refuse to load unless the tab is active, whereas most users appreciate tabs loading in the background. This behavior may not be specific to Firefox.

**Examples**:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/
https://www.chase.com/ (especially after login)

**Solution Requested**:
A way to override this behavior, allowing all content to load in Background tabs. Preferred solution is Firefox-specific, OS agnostic, and works with the examples above.

**Prior Research**:
It's possible, but not confirmed, that the web sites may be using `visibilitychange` or `window.onfocus` or `window.onblur` Handle Events or Event Listener techniques, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus).
The goal of this question is to override this. Greasemonkey?

**Solutions that DO NOT work**:
[Disable Page Visibility API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-page-visibility/?) Firefox Addon
[Always on focus](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/177284) userscript
"browser.tabs.loadInBackground" preference "true"
"browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground" preference "true"
"browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground" preference "true"
"browser.zoom.updateBackgroundTabs" preference "true"
"toolkit.lazyHiddenWindow" preference "false"

**Additional Notes**:
Browser successfully loads all other pages in background.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/492335/109803